# Boot-Loader Problem with External HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

My internal hard disk drive is broken and I can't afford a new one right now. I have an external hard drive, however. I tried to install Ubuntu to my external hard drive. It works till I shut my computer. I can't boot it after shutdown. I read some, and found out that it's because my external hard drive does not have a bootloader (GRUB) on it.

So, I installed boot-repair, but it did not work. After I installed Ubuntu 4-5 more times, I gave up and thought about asking you guys.

Here are my results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26095855/

What must I do now? Can you help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If UEFI sees drive as an external drive, then it only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, not /EFI/ubuntu files. And Boot-Repair has copied shimx64.efi into /EFI/Boot and renamed it. Can you boot in UEFI mode this entry `Boot0001* USB Hard Drive (UEFI)`?

Comment: @oldfred How can I do that? You want me to restart? I don't want to reinstall from USB, so I have to know what to do first. You want me to restart and enter BIOS and turn of legacy support?

Comment: Do not reinstall. Question was can you from UEFI boot menu, boot the USB hard drive entry?

Comment: @oldfred My computer says there's no operating system. It says install operating system to hard drive or something like that. I'll share the results. Thank you very much. However, in the boot-repair result, it says there's no bootloader. Is it normal? Because my internal hard drive is on my desk now, not plugged into my laptop.

Comment: Can you  please try what was suggested above (twice)? UEFI, if you don't know yet, is what replaces BIOS in modern PCs. At UEFI settings you should find something about the boot order (typically in the "Boot" menu).

Comment: Internal drive is where grub installed boot loader. So if unplugged & you did not copy boot files from internal drive's ESP to External drive's ESP, then you would not have any boot loader.  Or as first comment if Summary report is external drive: Can you boot in UEFI mode this entry Boot0001* USB Hard Drive (UEFI)?

Comment: Hey everyone, I still couldn't boot from my external harddisk. I booted from live usb again, and followed the steps in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/740253/how-to-install-grub-in-an-external-hard-drive It worked I guess. I'm writing these lines from my external harddisk-booted-computer right now. Sorry, I'm a newbie and again, sorry if I asked stupid questions. Thank you very much, friends. Thank you @MichaelBay . Thank you oldfred (I could not add your name,  sorry. It says "Only one additional user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified". Thank you very much.