# How to install Kubuntu 18.04 on an external hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap

In previous versions of Ubuntu, one needed to create a swap partition and a primary partition formatted as ext4, however, Ubuntu 18.04 uses a swap file instead of a swap partition.

So just to make sure, I only need to create a primary partition and the Ubiquity installer will take care of the rest, right?

Comment: Why the downvote? Would you please help and correct me instead of just downvoting and  going away?

Comment: There is no need to create partitions in advance, the installer can do it. Just select the correct device for installation, and then, yes, the installer "will take care of the rest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new installs Ubuntu 18.04 defaults to using a swap file instead of the swap partition used in previous releases. There is no need to create partitions in advance. Select an option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubiquity installer, and the Ubiquity installer will guide you through the rest. The *Guided* options are suitable for installing Ubuntu on an internal hard drive.

The *Manual* option is suitable for installing Ubuntu on an external hard drive. By choosing the *Manual* option in the *Installation type* screen, you can create or resize partitions for yourself, or choose multiple partitions for Kubuntu by following the instructions in the accepted answer to: [How to install Ubuntu on a portable external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive). There is no need to create partitions on the external hard in advance, unless you want to use part of the space on the external hard drive as a separate partition for storing data, etc. in which case you need to create unallocated space for installing Kubuntu alongside the partition that will be used for storing data, etc.

[image]
<sup>**Kubuntu (auto) under After partitioning indicates that Kubuntu partitioning will be done automatically.**</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I chose the first option in the menu and kubuntu was installed on the external hard disk, but it installed grub on my internal ssd :-(

Comment: [How to install Grub in an external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740253/how-to-install-grub-in-an-external-hard-drive)