# Problem running Ubuntu 20.04 on external drive

Tags: 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu on an external drive and when I am using it for a while it stops working and appears as seen in the image. Is there any way to solve it?

[image: Image of application icons after Ubuntu crashes]

Comment: Please provide an english translation, thanks.

Comment: No habla ingles ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  -Habla ingles por favor

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/946155/1372403