# SOLVED Ubuntu 22 from external replaced grub from internal ubuntu 22

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

On my PC i have Ubuntu 22, WIndows 11 and Kali(installed later) running
I also installed Ubuntu 22 onto an external SSD using the same PC, but sice then the grub from my internal computer wont work and only show the console without the external SSD plugged in. It is working though when i plug the external ssd in though.
I have also selected in the installation of the Ubuntu on the exteranl drive to create the EFI on the external but i couldnt find a EFI partition on the external drive.
On my internal ubuntu i have also tried running `sudo update-grub` but it didnt fix it.

Thank you in advance

Edit:
`sudo grub-install` worked

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/946155/1372403

Comment: Just boot into your internal Ubuntu and there run `sudo grub-install`.

Comment: Also add an ESP to external drive, update fstab with new UUID for ESP, make sure remounted, and reinstall grub. Most UEFI, when you disconnect an external drive delete or change UEFI entry. But you can always boot external from UEFI entry for a drive. Also add an entry on internal drive's grub.cfg to boot external. Depending on installer used, you may not have choice to add ESP/grub to external. Older Ubiquity:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Newer Ubuntu uses Subiquity  or some flavors use Calamares.

Comment: I have far less experience with Ubuntu Core 22 than Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but in general the last installed OS controls the boot process. You can use `update-grub` as you mention to make it recognize later versions of the OSes that were already noted, but that will **not** change the boot menu of what you see on boot unless that OS on which you ran `update-grub` already owns the boot process (ie. if you installed Kali Linux later; running `update-grub` won't help if run from Ubuntu).  You can use `grub-install` to change ownership of boot on 22.04 (*unsure about Ubuntu Core 22 sorry*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition)