No operating system found
I tried installing windows 10 on my external hard drive but now Ubuntu 23.10 won't boot... I do I resolve this. And the boot sequence is no longer showing any operating system

Boot from a live USB drive, and run boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. If that does not work, first install Windows, and then install Ubuntu 24.04 (which was released yesterday)

Does this answer your question? How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)

How to install Grub in an external hard drive? - Ask Ubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/740253/how-to-install-grub-in-an-external-hard-drive

thank you so installing windows then reinstalling ubuntu  worked

Not sure but,
Perhaps your, grub / boot-loader isn't working properly
(due to incorrect install procedure of win-10)
you can try "unplugging" your external HDD and check if your existing Linux is booting fine!
if yes, you can try re-installing win-10 on your external drive,
make sure you follow proper dual boot OS installation guide
